# Ambiguity errors with variadic templates and mixins

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am trying to create a callback registration class tat allows registration of callbacks against  string identifier for different types.  Each callback has the signature `void function( T val )` where `T` is the changing type.

I have created the following base registrar class that maps strings to functions.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template< typename ValueType >
class BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar 
{
public:
    typedef ValueType value_type;
    typedef BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar< value_type > type;
    typedef function< void( const value_type ) > signature_type;
    typedef map< string, signature_type > callback_map_type;

    /// @brief constructor
    BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar() : callbackMap_()
    {
    }

    /// @brief register a create callback 
    /// @param nodePath the path identifying the node in config database
    /// @param callback the callback to register
    type& RegisterCallback( string nodePath, signature_type callback )
    {
        callbackMap_.insert( make_pair( move(nodePath), callback ) );
        return *this;
    }

    void MakeCallback( const string& nodePath, value_type val )
    {
        // no checking assumes item is in map,
        // do not do this in production code
        auto iter = callbackMap_.find( nodePath );
        iter->second( val );
    }

private:
    callback_map_type callbackMap_;       ///< the callback map
};
```

I then use variadic templates to create a derived class for each of the types I want to support.

```
template< typename... Types >
class ConfigCallbackRegistrar : public BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<Types>... 
{
public:
    /// @brief constructor
    ConfigCallbackRegistrar() : BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<Types>()...
    {}
};
```

This is then typedefed as:

```
typedef ConfigCallbackRegistrar< uint32_t, string > CallbackRegistrar;
```

When I try to use this class as follows:

```
struct UintFtor
{
    void operator()( uint32_t val )
    {
        cout << val << "\n"; 
    }
};

struct StringFtor
{
    void operator ()( string val )
    {
        cout << val << "\n"; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    CallbackRegistrar registrar{};

    registrar.RegisterCallback( "SomeNode", UintFtor() );
    registrar.RegisterCallback( "SomeNode", StringFtor() );

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to compile this I get the following ambiguity errors:

```
variadic-wrap.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
variadic-wrap.cpp:87: error: request for member ‘RegisterCallback’ is ambiguous
variadic-wrap.cpp:27: error: candidates are: BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<ValueType>&  BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<ValueType>::RegisterCallback(std::string, std::function<void(ValueType)>) [with ValueType = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]
variadic-wrap.cpp:27: error:                 BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<ValueType>& BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<ValueType>::RegisterCallback(std::string, std::function<void(ValueType)>) [with ValueType = unsigned int]
variadic-wrap.cpp:88: error: request for member ‘RegisterCallback’ is ambiguous
variadic-wrap.cpp:27: error: candidates are: BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<ValueType>& BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<ValueType>::RegisterCallback(std::string, std::function<void(ValueType)>) [with ValueType = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]
variadic-wrap.cpp:27: error:                 BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<ValueType>& BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<ValueType>::RegisterCallback(std::string, std::function<void(ValueType)>) [with ValueType = unsigned int]
```

Calls to `MakeCallback` which takes a parameter of type `value_type` also produce the same ambiguity error.

How can I resolve this without an explicit cast of  `registrar` to the base class type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. All tat is needed is an extra level of indirection. In the Derived class I added a template function that dispatches to the correct base, as follows:

```
template< typename... Types >
class ConfigCallbackRegistrar : public BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<Types>...
{
    typedef ConfigCallbackRegistrar<Types...> type;
public:
    /// @brief constructor
    ConfigCallbackRegistrar() : BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<Types>()...
    {}

    template<typename T> 
    type& Register( string nodePath, 
            typename BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<T>::signature_type callback )
    {
        BasicConfigCallbackRegistrar<T>::RegisterCallback( std::move(nodePath), 
                std::move(callback) );
        return *this;
    } 
};
```

The calling code becomes:

```
int main()
{
    CallbackRegistrar registrar{};

    registrar.Register<uint32_t>( "SomeNode", UintFtor() );
    registrar.Register<string>( "SomeNode", StringFtor() );

    return 0;
}
```